# Powershell script works in Powershell, but not in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, powershell, exchange-server

I have a simple powershell script to enable a mailbox in Exchange called test.ps1.  Here is the script:

add-pssnapin microsoft.exchange.management.powershell.admin
Enable-Mailbox -Identity 'gi joe' -database 'myserver\myserver mailbox database 17'

If I go to the Powershell console and type

./test.ps1

It will run successfully.  However, if I call it in VB.net using

Process.Start("powershell", "test.ps1")

the terminal flashes too quickly for me to see what it says, and it doesn't create the mailbox.  Why does this happen, or how can I stop the terminal from disappearing before I can read the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see what is going wrong try this instead:

```
Process.Start("powershell", "-noexit -file c:\<path>\test.ps1")
```

I suspect the error you get is because you aren't providing a full path to test.ps1.

Another possibility is that your 32-bit VB app needs to launch 64-bit Powershell (snapin or module may only be available there).  In that case you need to invoke PowerShell by path and you have to use `SysNative` in your path to be able to see the 64-bit PowerShell dir.

```
var powerShellPath = "C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
Process.Start(powerShellPath , "-noexit -file c:\<path>\test.ps1")
```

Sorry that's probably not proper VB syntax but should get you going.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out the error is "no snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2." This is weird, because the first line of the script adds the snap in. Is there a way I can replace "powershell" to include powershell with all moduels? That way I won't need that line of code adding the snapin.

Comment: @Austin this sounds like you're running into a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue.  When you register a snapin in the 32-bit shell, it isn't automatically registered for the 64-bit shell and vice-versa.  Does your VB app run as 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: You're right, I changed the target cpu to Any CPU and it worked! However, this breaks another part of my application =( Is there a way to force Powershell to start in 32bit mode?

Comment: Yes, use the path to the 32-bit version of powershell e.g. `C:\Windows\SysWow64\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.  Of course, you might want to use the `System.Environment` class to get the `windir` environment variable, rather than hard code `c:\windows`.

Comment: Hmm I still get the same error. Do you have an idea why it works when I set it to Any CPU, but not when I set it to x86?

Comment: When you run AnyCPU the process loads as 64-bit so when you start process using just "powershell", the 64-bit version of Powershell will be launched.  It sounds like you need your VB app as 32-bit but you need to launch 64-bit PowerShell.  In that case, change the app to x86 and use a full path to the 64-bit version of PowerShell `C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.  Again, substitute the expansion of the WinDir env var for `C:\Windows`.

Comment: I've tried pointing it to both the 32bit version and the 64bit version of Powershell, but unless I set the target CPU to Any CPU it does not work. It simply ignores the "add-pssnapin" line of my script.

Comment: Are you using SysNative in the path? That's the only way to specify a path to 64-bit PowerShell from a 32-bit application.

Comment: It cannot find the folder path "SysNative".
Also, I shouldn't need to run 64bit Powershell since I always use 32bit. Plus, I'm developing this app for use with XP 32bit so I can't do that anyway.

Comment: Are you developing and testing on 32-bit XP?  Also, backing up for a moment, when you run the script from a PowerShell console and it works, is that PowerShell console 32-bit i.e. `[intptr]::size` returns 4?

Comment: No, I am developing on Windows 7 64bit. Yes, the script works when I run it from 32bit Powershell.

Comment: OK that's odd.  When you run as AnyCPU your VB.NET app runs 64-bit so when you start "powershell" (no path) it fires up the 64-bit version of PowerShell (should have x64 in titlebar) and the script works.  But if you switch to x86 on your VB.NET app, it will run as 32-bit, firing up a 32-bit PowerShell (x86 in titlebar) but that fails to run the script - saying "no snap-ins have been registered".  Yet when you run the script manually from a 32-bit PowerShell, the script works.  That's darn odd.  Are you starting PowerShell under different credentials or suppressing userprofile loading?

Comment: I'm running out of time for this application so I did it a cheap way: I simply created a new executable out of this and will reference it in my original application. That way the original app is x86 and this app is Any CPU. Thanks for your help!