# Using PowerShell in vb.net code to unblock files ends with error 'The system cannot find the file specified'

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I'm using the following code:

```
Dim start_info As New ProcessStartInfo("gci 'C:\Program Files\MyFolder\MyApp\' | Unblock-File") With {.UseShellExecute = False, .CreateNoWindow = True, .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden}
Dim pro As New Process With {.StartInfo = start_info}
pro.Start()
pro.WaitForExit()
MessageBox.Show("Unblock Files Exit Code: " & pro.ExitCode, "Exit " & "Code", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

If I type the command (gci 'C:\Program Files\MyFolder\MyApp' | Unblock-File) in Win PowerShell all works well, but if I run the code I get "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'" error.

Could anybody please help?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to invoke PowerShell, for example as shown in [Powershell script works in Powershell, but not in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851334/powershell-script-works-in-powershell-but-not-in-vb-net).

Answer (score 0):

Sorted by invoking 64 bit PowerShell

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
```